# Eliminate sensitive headers from spring RequestDumperFilter

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to configure Spring RequestDumperFilter so that it will not log specific headers that contain sensitive information (for example the "Authorization" header)?

Comment: What package are you getting that class from?

Comment: @tgdavies it's from org.apache.catalina.filters.RequestDumperFilter
Usage in Spring, for example:

    public FilterRegistrationBean requestDumperFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        Filter requestDumperFilter = new RequestDumperFilter();
        registration.setFilter(requestDumperFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        return registration;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the source https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/8e2aa5e45ce13388da62386e3cb1dbfa3b242b4b/java/org/apache/catalina/filters/RequestDumperFilter.java it appears there is no way to do that:

```
Enumeration<String> hnames = hRequest.getHeaderNames();
while (hnames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String hname = hnames.nextElement();
  Enumeration<String> hvalues = hRequest.getHeaders(hname);
  while (hvalues.hasMoreElements()) {
    String hvalue = hvalues.nextElement();
    doLog("            header", hname + "=" + hvalue);
  }
}
```

But it would be very easy to copy that file and modify it to do what you want.